# Linear independence, dimension of a space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $m\times m$ real, square matrix and take the $b = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}v_{k}$, $n < m$, where each $v_k$ is an eigenvector of A corresponding to a distinct eigenvalue $\lambda_k$, and $a_k \neq 0$.

Claim:

$\dim K = n$ where $ K = \text{span}\{b, Ab, \ldots, A^{n-1}b\}$.

I have approached this by attempting to show that the vectors in $K$ are linearly independent, i.e.
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_{i}A^{i}b = 0 \iff c_{i} = 0$$
but my progress seems to stall at a certain point. I look forward to any insight that may be offered to prove this claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint1: $b$ is a linear combination of the eigenvectors.

Hint2: Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Hint3: Knowing the eigenvalues of $A$, what can you say about the eighenvalues of $A^i$?